# Which buildings consume or produce power?

Tags: kittens-game

Recently (at least I think so) a new feature was added to the game: Power. Power is generated by some structures and consumed by others. The problem is, I don't know which buildings produce power. My overall power is now at about -20, with +5/-25, with the +5 coming from unknown.

Which buildings (including buildings from the space and religion tabs) can produce power? Which ones consume it?

Comment: Power (electricity) is actually not that new. It has been in the game for a long time. Check the wiki for the details: http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Energy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Buildings producting energy (ordered by production):

- Satellite: +1 (after researching Solar Satellites)
- Steamworks: +1
- Solar Farm: +2 (+3 with Photovoltaic Cells)
- Hydro Plant: +5 (+5.75 with Hydro Plant Turbines)
- Magneto: +5
- Reactor: +10 (+12.5 with Cold Fusion)
- Sunlifter: +30

#### Buildings consuming energy (ordered by consumption):

- Oil Well: -1 (consumes energy only after Pumpjack has been researched)
- Calciner: -1
- Bio Lab: -1 (consumes energy only after Biofuel Processing has been researched)
- Satellite: -1 (before researching Solar Satellites)
- Factory: -2
- Accelerator: -2
- Lunar Outpost: -5
- Space Station: -10
- Moon Base: -10
- Orbital Array -20
- Chronosphere: -20

For more info, check out the [Kittens Game Wiki](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Energy).

Answer (score 3):

The building statistics tell you.

[image]